# Conditional Logistic Regression in SPSS: data preparation

Tags: conditional-statements, regression, logistic-regression, spss

I need to perform a conditional logistic regression, and unfortunately must use SPSS in this case. The data should be composed of groups, in which there is a subject and 3 matched control. Each combined group should be numbered serially, so it could be used as strata. Suppose I have column A:

- A. Diagnosis
- 1
- 0
- 0
- 0
  ..
  How do I add to it column B with group numbers?
- A.**Diagnosis**    B.**Group**
- 1                         1
- 0                         1
- 0                         1
- 0                         1
- 1                         2
- 0                         2
- 0                         2
- 0                         2
  ..
  Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
compute group=trunc(($casenum-0.1)/4)+1.
```

Note that this will not work if the order changes or if there are groups with less or more than 4 lines.

Comment: Hi eli-k. Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm afraid the syntax results in null variable. Perhaps I should try to rewrite the problem: what basically is needed is a column of group id that (1,2,3,4...n) with 4 cases only in each group.

Comment: the result should fit your description. maybe you didn't **run pending transformations** - find this in the TRANSFORM menu, or use <ctrl>+G, or add another line of syntax with `execute.`

Comment: Yep, I forgot adding the execute command. Works excellent now. Thank you so much, this is huge help!